# Span acting like div

Tags: html, css

I have this code, where I planned to have three spans side by side displaying the step a person is at signing up for my website.  However, the spans are acting like divs and going onto the next line.  I have no idea why this is happening.  To my understanding, the spans should only take up the width they need, not an entire line

```
      <div class="row stepRow">
    <div class="col-12-md ">
      <div id="stepDisplay">
        <span class="stepBlock">
          <h3 class="headerStep">Step 1</h3>
          <p class="descStep">Basic Details</p>
        </span>
        <span class="stepBlock">
          <h3 class="headerStep">Step 2</h3>
          <p class="descStep">More Details</p>
        </span>
        <span class="stepBlock">
          <h3 class="headerStep">Step 3</h3>
          <p class="descStep">Payment Details</p>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
```

//in seperate css file

```
.stepBlock {
  display: display;
  text-align: center;
}

.headerStep .descStep {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if display: display; is a typo, but you would want display: inline-block and it should work fine.

Comment: Sorry, that was a mistake.  thanks for catching it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the `comma(,)` between `.headerStep` and `.descStep`. It should be like following.

```
.headerStep, .descStep {
    display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using h3 element inside span which takes all available width. Either replace h3 or set its maximum length

Comment: Yep and the code is semantically incorrect by putting block elements inside inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution you are looking for

```
      <div class="row stepRow">
<div class="col-12-md ">
  <div id="stepDisplay">
    <span class="stepBlock">
      <h3 class="headerStep">Step 1</h3>
      <p class="descStep">Basic Details</p>
    </span>
    <span class="stepBlock">
      <h3 class="headerStep">Step 2</h3>
      <p class="descStep">More Details</p>
    </span>
    <span class="stepBlock">
      <h3 class="headerStep">Step 3</h3>
      <p class="descStep">Payment Details</p>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
.stepBlock {
  display: display;
  text-align: center;
}

.headerStep .descStep {
  display: inline;
}

h3,p {
  display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/faxm0jwd/)

```
.stepBlock {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
}

.headerStep, .descStep {
  display: block;
}
```